# Querying on association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck in a rails problem, being a noob here. Given the following relationships.

```
conversation has_many messages
messages belongs_to conversation
messages has_many documents and vice versa, through document_messages
```

I need to find all documents in that conversation for a given conversation id. I got it working with following

`c.messages.map(&:documents).select{ |doc| doc.length > 0 }`

But as I understand it takes everything from database and does filtering on the application, but I need to filter it on the database (where clause?) for e.g. `conversation.messages.where(document.exists).map(&:documents)`

Edit: I came up with following sql query which is working

```
SELECT document.id FROM
conversation INNER JOIN message
ON conversation.id = message.c_id
INNER JOIN document_messages
ON message.id = document_messages.m_id
INNER JOIN document
ON document.id = document_messages.d_id
where conversation.id = given_id
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you seeing an errors?

Comment: @GavinMiller I have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally managed to write the query.

```
Document.joins(document_messages: [{ message: :conversation }]).where(conversations: { id: conversation_id})
```

which can be simplified to

```
 Document.joins(messages: :conversation).where(conversations: { id: conversation_id})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Through association: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

```
Conversation
  has_many :messages
  has_many :documents, through: :messages
end

Messages
  belongs_to :conversation
  has_many :documents
end
```

Using this, you can do the following:

```
  conversation = Conversation.first
  conversation.documents
```

And you have all documents of a conversation!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely confident with how this plays with a join table but this could be what you need?

#### https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Something like:

```
messages = conversation.messages.includes(:documents)
documents = messages.documents
```